# Reading space separated numbers from text file to an array of ints (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, file-io

I need some help reading space separated ints from a text file to an array . here is an example of the text file : "69 2 189 1876" . the amount of the ints is known (4 in this example). I tried googling but still haven't found a satisfying solution . This is my first time doing file I/O so please go easy on me . Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Have you tried something? Are you able to at least open the file and get the numbers somewhow (as string for instacce)?

Comment: You need to show an attempt, then people will be quite willing to tell you what mistakes you've made and how to improve it. Do you know how to read a single `int`, and print it back out? Do you know about `std::Vector`?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `std::copy`:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

std::vector<int> array;
std::ifstream stream("filename");
std::copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(stream),
          std::istream_iterator<int>(),
          std::back_inserter(array));
```

If you want to read just the first N one, use `std::copy_n` instead of `std::copy`.

Comment: @user3789296 A vector is most certainly an [array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Array_data_structure). If you don't want to use `std::vector` for whatever reason, and you know the size upfront, you can use `std::array` and pass its begin iterator instead of `std:back_inserter(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is shown a possible approach:

```
const size_t N = 4;
int a[N] = {};

std::ifstream in( "YourTextFile" );

size_t n = 0;

while ( n < N && in >> a[n] ) ++n;
```

If the number of read values is not known then instead of the array you can use standard class std::vector. For example

```
std::ifstream in( "YourTextFile" );
std::vector<int> v;

int num;    

while ( in >> num ) v.push_back( num );
```

You can reserve some initial memory for the vector if you are show that the file contains at least the number of elements that are reserved in the vector. For example

```
v.reserve( 4 );
```

Comment: I want to store them in an array not a vector

Comment: @user3789296  There is written in my post how to store data in array if the number of data is known.